# Google API Batch returns 401

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-js-client

Doing two or more requests in one batch at once leads to a 401 for each request.

```
const batch = gapi.client.newBatch();
batch.add(gapi.client.drive.files.list());
batch.add(gapi.client.drive.files.list());
batch.then((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

The error is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Using only one *batch.add* works perfectly fine. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Why? What do I do wrong?

Comment: I think that your snippet in your question is correct. Although I'm not sure whether this is a directly solution, for example, how about reducing the returned data size? It's ``gapi.client.drive.files.list({'pageSize': 1, 'fields': "files(name)"})``. By this, each request returns only one information of file. If this was not the solution, can you provide your script including the OAuth2 process?

Comment: The query is just a simple example. Batch does not work, that is the problem.

Comment: In my environment, I couldn't replicate your situation. I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Directly from the documentation [handle errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials)

> 401: Invalid Credentials
>   Invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either expired or invalid.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization",
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```

> Suggested action: Refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described in [Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth).

[Batch](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/batch) documentation.

```
var searchRequest = function(name) {
  return gapi.client.request({
    'path': 'plus/v1/people',
    'params': {'query': name}
   });
};
var searchAlvin = searchRequest('Alvin');
var searchSimon = searchRequest('Simon');

// Adding just the request
batch.add(searchAlvin);
// Adding the request with an ID
batch.add(searchSimon, {'id': 'searchSimon'});
```

Comment: I wrote: *Using only one batch.add works perfectly fine. It doesn't make any sense to me.*

Comment: @Viatorus that does not change the meaning of the error message or the possible solution for the error message.   Each of your requests in the batch must be authenticated.  Not the single batch request itself.

Comment: So what do I have to do to authenticate each request inside a batch request? I have a valid access token from the user. Otherwise I couldn't do any request.

Comment: I think you should try reading though the documentation on how batching is suposed to work your code does not look like the docuemtation